# How to add/update the image URL link in the Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to add the URL link in the Firebase database (in database not in storage)

1) i register Auth and save the data in the "Database", but the Image URL i put it empty first, after that i want to add the image on it and save the image URL in the database

Something like this :
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTsNU.jpg)

2) now i want to add the image on it and save the URL, but the database become like this : [After save the URL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dktW.jpg)

3) but i want save the image URL like this : [The database that i want.....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVhSa.jpg)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

what can i change in my code ?

Here is my code:

```
 private void saveinfo() { //create info java class
    if(mImageUri != null){
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+ getFileExtension(mImageUri));
      mUploadTask =  fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
                        Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();


                        User in = new User();

                        in.setIcurl(downloadUrl.toString());

                        FirebaseDatabase  database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = database.getReference();

                        mDatabaseRef.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("icurl").setValue(in);

                        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"no image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: The documentation has a great example of how to get the download URL after uploading a file. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url Hint: using a tight loop (`while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());`) is usually a bad idea, as you're making your app unresponsive.

Comment: I already get the URL, but now i want add the URL in the firebase database that i already create, but it update the database that something i don't want .... @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: What's `User` in `User in = new User();`? Also check your logcat output for any error messages. And I'd still recommend using the approach from the documentation to get the download URL.

Comment: Final note: if the same problem occurs when you just try to write any value to that location, you have an opportunity to reduce the amount of code you're sharing with us. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the best chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you stored a object inside (i.e User) that is the reason for this behaviour
Change the below line     `mDatabaseRef.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("icurl").setValue(in);`

to this

```
mDatabaseRef.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("icurl").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
```